# Passar valor de input hidden para label

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Pessoal preciso passar o conteúdo de um input hidden para um label:

```
<div class="form" ng-init="rodar()">
<input type="hidden" ng-model="cadastro" name="cad" id="cad">
<label id="text"></label> 
<script>
    function rodar()
    { 
        var valor = document.getElementById('cad').value; 
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = valor;
    } 
    window.onload = rodar(); 
</script>
```

Pelo que vi o erro está ao pegar a variavel do input hidden (cad), pois se eu setar o var valor = 1; funciona e aparece o label

Comment: <label id="text">{{cadastro}}</label> não serviria?

Answer (score -1):

Porque como o type é hidden ele funciona como um boolean, caso você coloque 1 ele passa para verdadeiro e aparece

o hidden não pode ser o type, entendeu

Answer (score -1):

Acontece que esse input não tem o atributo value que tu ta pegando no JS.

Tenta assim, colocando o atributo value no input:

`<div class="form" ng-init="rodar()">
<input type="hidden" ng-model="cadastro" name="cad" id="cad" value="Teste">
<label id="text"></label> 
<script>
    function rodar()
    { 
        var valor = document.getElementById('cad').value; 
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = valor;
    } 
    window.onload = rodar(); 
</script>`